# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to automatically send an entry with the username admin and password 0000 to the /admin url from the login screen, and I want my peer there. I have a data in my hand, there is a user saying that there is admin in it, and its authority is true. I am comparing this data with the data from the login screen. (by the way i have a separate module called admin)

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
        import { CanActivate, Router,} from "@angular/router";
    import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


    @Injectable({
        providedIn:'root'
    })

    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

        dataUserx:any;

        constructor(private dataAuth:LoginComponent, private router:Router){

            this.dataAuth.getAuth().subscribe((data:any) => {
                this.dataUserx = data.value;
            },error =>{
                console.log(error)
            })


            


        }

        ngOnInit() {
            

            this.canActivate(this.dataUserx);
        }

        canActivate(value){
            
            if(value==1){

                return true;
            } 
            else{
                
                return false;
            }
            

        }
    }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable,of } from 'rxjs';

import { Validators,ValidatorFn,AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from '../users';
import { usersService } from '../users.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  
  users:Array<User>;

  users$: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  
  constructor(private dataUser:usersService, private fb:FormBuilder,private router: Router) {

    this.dataUser.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log('Data: ', data);
      
    },error =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
    
  }

  public userSignUpForm = this.fb.group({

    firstName: ["",[Validators.required]],
    password:["",[Validators.required]]
    
  })


  get firstName(){
    return this.userSignUpForm.get('firstName');
  }



  onSubmit() { 
    let a = this.users.findIndex(param => param.name==this.userSignUpForm.value.firstName)
    if(a >-1){
      this.users$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.users[a].authority);

      console.log("Değer değer",this.users$)
      
      if(this.users$.value == true)
      {
        console.log("geldik")
        this.router.navigate(['admin']);
      }
      
    } 
    else{
      window.alert('Please first SignUP!')
      return location.reload();
    
    }
    
    this.userSignUpForm.reset();    
    
  }

  getAuth(): Observable<any>{

    return this.users$;

  }

}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
    import { Product } from './product';
    import { BehaviorSubject, from, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { User } from './users';


    @Injectable({
        providedIn:'root'
    })

    export class usersService{

        dataEmitter$:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([
            {name:'admin', password:'0000', authority:true },
            {name:'Guest', password:'123', authority:false },
            ])

            getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{

                return this.dataEmitter$;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Constructor on  AuthGuard is incorrectly injecting dataAuth:LoginComponent instead make it dataAuth:usersService.

Comment: @Pankaj If I replace it with this, what will happen if I'm trying to read the users$ data in the login component?

Comment: Should work. In case it doesn't try creating a repro of the issue on stackblitz.com and paste the link in your question. That'll help others to help you